# How to ssh to my Ubuntu from outside the local network?

Tags: linux, ssh, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel

Suppose that a Linux server A is in a local network with IP 192.168.0.90, and I have another Linux server B outside this local network, with IP 203.107.90.80. I want to get access to  server A via ssh on server B. How can I do that?

I have tried reverse ssh tunneling following the instructions from this page http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling, but when I tried to ssh to A on B it told me that the connection is closed by the remote host. I check the ssh_config and the ssh port is 22.

Comment: Is that a typo 192.186... did you mean 192.168 ?

Comment: @lain Ah...I am sorry for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is an unblocked route between the two networks, *and an ssh server is running on the target system*, you should be able to connect. Make sure sshd is running on the server to which you are attempting to connect.

Comment: You are right! I don't know that I have to install openssh-server LOL

Answer (score 0):

An unblocked route between the two networks is achieved by setting up a static route on the router to which Server B is connected specifying how to access the subnet to which Server A is connected